# I have a Parent Agreement and it has two child Agreement in related list. On Agreement object it has a lookup called parent Agreement

Tags: trigger, workflow, process-builder, visual-workflow

I  have a Parent Agreement and it has two child Agreements in related list.  If i choose this  parent Agreement in another Agreement ParentAgreement-lookup field then all the related child Agreement of this parentAgreement has to be added to this new Agreement?

1.I will create one agreement this is parent agreement(name : A ).
2.  I  will create two agreements( B & C) with parent agreement as (A).
3. Now I will create another agreement (D ) and here i'll choose parent agreement as(A) and now here i want to add all the child agreement of agreement(A) has to added to D .Here related records (A)- Agreement's ,B and C agreements has to added in D Agreement record.
4. Now at last the D records has to be with Parent agreement as A and in related list(Child Agreements) it has to show B & C .

Is this possible to do,If it is possible please let me know how can I achieve it .

Comment: Is this object Agreement a standard object (Contract) or is it custom? How did you set up the parent relationship? Because aside the Account hierarchy that possibility does not exist directly in Salesforce, see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326493&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Agreement is custom object (from managed package). And  parent relationship just created a lookup  with agreement as parent object in Agreement object.

Comment: As Agreement is a custom object from a managed package, can you already see a related list on the Agreement record? If not then try to add the related list via Page Layout. If you cannot do that, try to contact the provider of the managed package for further help, because it is not Salesforce standard but customized and I cannot help you further...

Comment: Just mind that generally a lookup relationship does not have any hierarchy included...

Comment: Yeah am having a related list . My use case  is of adding first agreement records related list to second agreement related list. with the help of the lookup field named parent agreement( here we will select first record ).

Comment: A related list has only limited possibilities for customization. Thus, for this requirement I think you should contact the provider of the managed package as I also cannot see how the related list is implemented into Salesforce and I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Or maybe it helps to mention the package you are working with to address Stack Exchange users with experience in this field.

Comment: Apttus managed package

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Account hierarchy if you click on that symbol on the top of the record right next to the Account name. If you use the relationship "Parent Account" then the children get automatically assigned in the Account hierarchy and you do not have to add anything in addition.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. Please can you  help with the updated question requirement. As there will be no view hierarchy in Agreement object.